# unable to remove listener from mongodb change stream 'change' event

Tags: node.js, mongodb, eventemitter, changestream

I figured the [mongodb change stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) extends the [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) class, so I tried removing events I installed by using the removeListener function.
After calling removeListener on the change stream it still fired on change. May be I'm just using the wrong function reference when removing, but I can not see how.

I found out removeAllListeners does remove the attached listener. But I need to be in control what listener to remove.

```
const change_listener = (change) => {
    console.log(change_stream.listenerCount("change"))
    change_stream.removeListener("change", change_listener)
    console.log(change_stream.listenerCount("change"))
}
change_stream.on("change", change => change_listener(change))
```

should output
1
0

but it outputs
1
1

and the listener goes on listening.

Using .once instead of .on only helps half the way. I would still need removeListener because I need to be able to cancel the listener early.

Comment: could you use `.once` instead of `.on`?

Comment: I need to be able to cancel the listener in case. Thanks for the hint though! Good to know this is also possible

Comment: if you look at the docs of `EventEmitter` right below `removeAllListeners` there is another function where you can specify the event as well as the function.

Comment: Well, if you mean removeListener, thats the one Im describing here that is not working as I expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the function you are removing.

This should work:

```js
const change_listener = (change) => {
    console.log(change_stream.listenerCount("change"))
    change_stream.removeListener("change", change_listener)
    console.log(change_stream.listenerCount("change"))
}
change_stream.on("change", change_listener)
```

Note that `change => change_listener(change)` is a function and it is different from `change_listener`

Comment: This is of course exactly the problem and has nothing to do with mongo change streams... Thanks a lot for your help and for looking closely!